# Getting incorrect colors while scaling up CCSprite

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, textures, scale, ccsprite

I'm getting a strange effect while scaling up a CCSprite loaded from a PVR texture. My original sprite is a simple solid color rectangle but I end up having a dithered color from both edges (left and right) with big scaling (ex: [mySprite setScaleX:100.0]). Note that this doesn't occur when I load my sprite from a standalone PNG file. Any idea what goes wrong or what special parameter could be missing ? BTW, I use TexturePacker and generating PNG textures is not better.
Thx.

**[UPDATE]** First image is the base sprite I want to expand ("test.png", real size is 3x30pix, here I zoomed 4 times for visibility purpose).

[image]

Second image is the expected result (the one I get when loaded from a standalone PNG file).

[image]

Code used:

```
aSprite = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"test.png"];
[self addChild:aSprite];
[aSprite setScaleX:300.0];
```

Third image is the result when loaded from the PVR texture.

[image]

Code used:

```
aSprite = [CCSprite spriteWithSpriteFrameName:@"test"];
[self addChild:aSprite];
[aSprite setScaleX:300.0];
```

Comment: A picture? What do you mean?

Comment: a picture of the issue you described because a picture says more than words ;)

Comment: Oops sorry, I added screens and code. Thx

Comment: that's the filtering applied by the GPU. Try setting aliasTexParameters (method on cctexture2d) on the test.png texture.